# Insert a Multiselect field into an array field

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to insert chosen option on the multi select field(from the HTML form) into the an array, that later gets passed into to the **JIRA API**.

The following is the multi select field, which I populate with values from the database:

```
<div class="s-10 1-8">
    <select id="insightList" multiple="multiple" name="arisUserGroup[]">
        <optgroup label="User Group">
            <?php
            $result = DB::getInstance()->get('vwcustomfieldsoptions',array('id','=',14923));
            foreach($result->results() as $result)
            { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $result->custid ?>"><?php echo $result->customvalue ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

The following is the method I use to create the new array with values from the HTML form:

```
public function userPersmissions($summary, $dbName, $userId, $arisUserGroup, $arisFolderPath)
{
    $json = Array ( "fields" => Array (
        "project" => Array
        ( "id" => 19806 ),
        "summary" => $summary,
        "issuetype" => Array ( "name" => "User Permissions" ),

        "customfield_14922" =>Array (
            "id" => $dbName
        ),
        "customfield_14447" =>$userId,

        "customfield_14923" =>Array (
            "id" => $arisUserGroup
        ),

        "customfield_15579" =>$arisFolderPath

    )
    );

    return $json;
}
```

I then turn this above associative array into a json array and pass it to the JIRA rest API, with the following method:

```
public function processArray($json)
{
    $url_send ="http://jira.food.co.za:8091/rest/api/2/issue/";
    $str_data = json_encode($json);

    $data=json_encode($str_data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_send);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($str_data),'X-Stream: true'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str_data);
    $result1 = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result1;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"ARIS User Group":"data was not an
>   array"}}

The format of the multiselect field in json is:

```
"customfield_10008": [ {"value": "red" }, {"value": "blue" }, {"value": "green" }]
```

The link to the json I am trying to use is: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue

Also when I do var_dump on the multiselect I get an empty string. Meaning the issue starts there.

Comment: hi @RyanVincent  , this is the link: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue

Comment: When I do a var_dump on data passed form multselect field. I get string(0) "", so I think the issue starts right there, and I am not sure how to resolve it. @RyanVincent I updated the question